# how to prove that the hash function h(x) = x² mod 4 yields only to 0 and 1

Tags: hash, hashtable

How can I prove that the hash function `h(x) = x² mod 4` yields only to `{0, 1}`, with x as an element of the natural numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first cover the even numbers, `2n` (where `n` is a natural number):

> `(2n)2
>   = (2n)(2n)
>   = (2)(n)(2)(n)
>   = (2)(2)(n)(n)
>   = 4n2
>   = 4(n2)`

That's an exact multiple of four so the remainder when dividing by four will *always* be zero.

---

Now let's cover the odd numbers, `2n + 1`:

> `(2n + 1)2
>   = (2n + 1)(2n + 1)
>   = (2n)(2n) + (2n)(1) + (1)(2n) + (1)(1)
>   = 4n2 + 2n + 2n + 1
>   = 4n2 + 4n + 1
>   = 4(n2 + n) + 1`

That's exactly one more than a multiple of four hence the remainder when dividing by four will *always* be one.

---

Now, let's look at any natural numbers that are neither even *nor* odd.

Wait a minute, there *aren't* any. I guess that means we're done :-)

---

And, before anyone points out that some languages may give a *negative* remainder when the arguments are negative, that doesn't actually apply here since the square of a natural number can never *be* negative.

Comment: You could just square 0, 1, 2, and 3 mod 4 and see that the results are 0, 1, 0, and 1.

Comment: @James, that is not a proof since it only applies to the set `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, not the set of all natural numbers. What you say would be true if the expression involved `(x mod 4)^2` but not for `(x^2) mod 4` - a proof needs to be exhaustive across the *entire* domain of the function (if you have extra information that explains *why* you only need to show it for those numbers, that really should be part of your proof).